# SQL How to add two dates in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Im trying to compute daily total working hours  from two shift morning and afternoon. The columns for morning shift are TimeIN and BreakOut and afternoon BreakIN and TimeOut but Im not getting the total working hours.

TIA. Any help will be appreciated.

```
declare @timein datetime ='2014-10-29 07:40:14.000'
,@breakout datetime = '2014-10-29 12:05:11.000'
,@breakin datetime ='2014-10-29 15:06:14.000'
,@timeout datetime ='2014-10-29 19:05:09.000'
,@totAM int, @totPM int , @totWorkHrs datetime

set @totAM = DATEDIFF ( second , @timein , @breakout )
set @totPM = DATEDIFF ( second , @breakin , @timeout )
set @totWorkHrs = @totAM + @totPM

Result:
@totAM = 15897
@totPM = 14335
@totWorkHrs = 30232

Output:
08:39:xx
```

Comment: What are you getting, and what are you _expecting_ to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total working hours from AM to PM will be

```
declare @timein datetime ='2014-10-29 07:40:14.000'
,@breakout datetime = '2014-10-29 12:05:11.000'
,@breakin datetime ='2014-10-29 15:06:14.000'
,@timeout datetime ='2014-10-29 19:05:09.000'
,@totAM int, @totPM int, @totHrs int, @totMins int, @totSecs int, @totAMPM int , @totWorkHrs datetime

set @totAM = DATEDIFF ( second , @timein , @breakout )

set @totPM = DATEDIFF ( second , @breakin , @timeout )

SET @totAMPM = (@totPM+ @totAM)

SET @totHrs = @totAMPM/3600
SET @totMins = (@totAMPM % 3600) / 60
SET @totSecs = @totAMPM % 60


Select @totHrs as Hours, @totMins as minutes,  @totSecs  as Seconds
```

Comment: Perfect!   I use google convert tools and it shows 8.39778. What does 3600 and % 3600 do?

Comment: @r2c3: We can get total hrs by dividing total seconds by 3600. 3600 because 1 hrs has 60 mins and per mins has 60 sec so eventually 60*60=3600. But for calculating minutes, we are using Modulo operator(%) to get remainder of total seconds and then we divide remainder by 60 to get actual minutes. And the same thing follows for seconds.

Comment: confirmed result. @Paresh Jadhav

Comment: @r2c3 : If you got your solution, you can upvote the answer and click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be You are looking Like this:

```
declare @timein datetime ='2014-10-29 07:40:14.000'
,@breakout datetime = '2014-10-29 12:05:11.000'
,@breakin datetime ='2014-10-29 15:06:14.000'
,@timeout datetime ='2014-10-29 19:05:09.000'
,@totAM int, @totPM int , @totWorkHrs datetime

set @totAM = DATEDIFF ( second , @timein , @breakout )
set @totPM = DATEDIFF ( second , @breakin , @timeout )




SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@totAM/3600)  
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(@totAM%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@totAM%60),2)as TOTAM 


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@totPM/3600)  
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(@totAM%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@totAM%60),2)as TOTPM
```

**`OUTPUT`**

```
TOTAM
4:24:57

TOTPM
3:24:57
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(@totAM+@totPM)/3600)  
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),((@totAM+@totPM)%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(@totAM+@totPM)%60),2)as TotalTime 

TotalTime
8:23:52
```

Comment: Almost close but I need to add TOTAM and TOTPM as Total working hours in a day. Thanks.

Comment: @Ganesh: But answer you are getting is not correct. Just recheck the TotalPM.